# Get last commit of file in github actions PR

Tags: github, github-actions, github-ci

I am struggling with the following Problem. I need to get the last commit that changed a file. In my local repository everything works fine, but in my github actions merge pipeline it seems as if github creates its own commit for the whole project (all files have the same new commit hash).

Is there a way how I can get the real last commit of that file?

```sh
git rev-list --all --no-merges -1 path/to/file.txt
```

This works in my local repository - but in github actions on a PR, all files have this new commit ID (that I can't see in the web interface on the source branch...

Comment: Your issue here is that GitHub will do a *shallow clone* depending on how you set up your GitHub action. A shallow clone has only one commit in it (or only a few, but the default is 1 here) so every file is associated with that one commit. You need to get the history, i.e., the earlier commits, to find out which is the last commit that *changed* the file (identical copies exist in every commit after that one).

Comment: Thank you a lot for pointing me in this direction - apart from only cloning 1 commit, it also clones some PR branch..